# WebRequest being decoded?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a string that stores a URL that contains %26 for & at one point in the URL, because that is required for the URL that I am trying to call.

I print the URL string to the console before making the

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURL);
```

and if I copy and paste the URL that is printed, then I am able to get to the desired target.

However, when I connect and get the response with

```
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
```

it fails (the URL makes an update to another page, and the update is made when I copy and paste the URL that is printed, but not when I run the HttpWebResponse...).

Does this have something to do with the encoding/decoding of the URL string when the WebRequest is created?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say copy/paste, do you copy/paste the URL in the browser?

Comment: What do you mean it makes an update? You mean it redirects?

Comment: By copy/paste, I mean that I copy the URL that is displayed on the console and paste it into a web browser, it performs the correct behavior.  By "makes an update" the URL includes another URL that it redirects to as long as the other parameters passed in the original URL pass error checking.

Comment: What exactly is the update doing? Is it posting some data? What does it do? Did you try debugging the app and see what is submitted...?

Comment: I tried debugging the app, and the correct URL is being used when the Create method for the WebRequest is being created, but I don't know what other debugging I can do...

Comment: no.. tell us more. What are you trying to do? What does the update do? it may not he the URL issue. There can be other issues.

Comment: What is the error? I bet the problem is the redirect.

Comment: Here is an example of the format of the URL string...   https://WWW.mywebsite.com/direct/my_test_portal.jsp?param1=00D&param2=06E&useSecure=true&jse=0&action=myAction&username=user@test.com&pw=password123&startURL=apex/doMyUpdate?paramKey=abc-123%26param2Key=https%3a%2f%2f127.0.0.1  When I copy and paste this into a web browser, I can see the update reflected on a page that contains the info that I am updating.  However, it does not update when I Create with this URL in C#.  The paramKey and param2Key at the end SHOULD contain the %'s for the redirect to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your url. Try this link [URL Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

Comment: When I encode, the URL turns into...https%3a%2f%2f...so it does not seem like that is correct.  With the way I had it set up before, I could at least send a URL to "log in" with a username and password, and then send this second URL I am trying to send as described in the original problem.  When I encode the URL, I cannot even send the first URL successfully.

Comment: I don't quiet understand, please enlighten me. When you do url encode, normally it will encode your url to something that a browser/http understands that's why it looks like https%3a%2f%2f... that's what url encode does.

Comment: The URL string that I use to create the WebRequest is as follows: https://www.mywebsite.com/direct/my_test_portal.jsp?param1=00D&param2=06E&useSecure=true&jse=0&action=myAction&username=user@test.com&pw=password123&startURL=apex/doMyUpdate?paramKey=abc-123%26param2Key=https%3a%2f%2f127.0.0.1 which if I copy and paste into a web browser, it performs the specified action.  I need the last two parameters (paramKey and param2Key) to have the %'s when the request is made.